# Chef purpose of cwd attribute on script resource

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

What is the purpose of cwd attribute in script resource? For some reason the running the first block works but the second one doesn't work as intended (i.e. cloning the git repo under `/var/apps`)

```
script 'clone_repo' do
  interpreter "bash"
  code <<-EOH
    cd /var/apps
    git clone https://gitlab.com/dsura/test-go-web-app.git
    EOH
  not_if { ::File.directory?("/var/apps/test-go-web-app") }
end
```

and

```
script 'clone_repo' do
  interpreter "bash"
  cwd ::File.dirname('/var/apps')
  code <<-EOH
    git clone https://gitlab.com/dsura/test-go-web-app.git
    EOH
  not_if { ::File.directory?("/var/apps/test-go-web-app") }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `File.directory` is a method that exists, but if you mean `cwd '/var/apps'` then there isn't a difference. It sets the working directory before running the subprocess (aka. the script). This matters more for the `execute` resource where you might not want to use `cd` like that, but `script` inherits from `execute` so it just comes along for the ride.

You could write that whole thing more concisely as:

```
execute 'git clone https://gitlab.com/dsura/test-go-web-app.git /var/apps/test-go-web-app' do
  creates '/var/apps/test-go-web-app'
end
```

Or use a git resource for even less:

```
git '/var/apps/test-go-web-app' do
  action :checkout
  repository 'https://gitlab.com/dsura/test-go-web-app.git'
end
```

It you leave off the `action :checkout`, the default `:sync` action will update to the `master` branch each time Chef runs which might be better too.

Comment: Sorry it's supposed to be `dirname`

Comment: `dirname('/var/apps') == '/var'` which is probably not what you meant either, but the rest of the answer applies :)